# System of equations in group

Tags: group-theory

Let $u_1,u_2,a \in G$, where $G$ is some group. I want to determine whether $u_1 u_2=u_2 u_1$ using the system of equations in $G$
\begin{align*}
u_1  u_2&=a^{-1}u_1u_2a && ~~\,u_2u_1=a^{-1}u_2u_1a &&
u_1^2u_2=u_2u_1^2\\
\mathrm{ord}\, u_1&=4  && \mathrm{ord}\, u_2=2\,.&&
\end{align*}
I've tried to embed this group in $S_n$ and use cycle structure of $u_1,u_2 $ along with some properties of conjugation in $S_n$, but it gave me nothing at all, so I have no clue how to solve the problem.

Comment: How does $a$ play a role?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These five conditions do not force $u_1,u_2$ to commute.
E.g. they hold in
$$G:=\Bbb Z\times D_8$$
where $\Bbb Z$ is generated by $a$ and the dihedral group $D_8$ is generated by $u_1,u_2$ with $u_1$ of order $4,$ $u_2$ of order $2,$ and $u_2u_1u_2=u_1^{-1}.$

Comment: Are you identifying OP's "$a$" with your "$(a,1)$"?

Comment: @Devo I have no "$(a,1)$" because I prefered considering both factors as *subgroups* of the direct product. This makes the notations less heavy.